# Vue2 How to use nested <template> tags?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using Vue2's latest version.

I have 2 components; 1st component:

```
<stack>
    <template #first>
        <template #cell(details)="row">
            {{ row.details ? "Hide" : "Show" }}
        </template>
    </template>
</stack>
```

2nd component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <slot name="first"></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                row: {
                    name: 'Test',
                    details: true
                }
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

I want to simply insert the contents of the `<template #first>` from the 1st component into the slot in the 2nd component while maintaining everything inside the `<template #first>` tag.

So the desired outcome would look like this; the slot would be replaced with the contents of the `<template #first>` tag:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <template #cell(details)="row">
            {{ row.details ? "Hide" : "Show" }}
        </template>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                row: {
                    name: 'Test',
                    details: true
                }
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

However, the 1st component does not work like this. It says that I cannot have a `template` inside a `template`. Is this actually possible what I'm trying to achieve here? If yes, how?

Comment: The 2nd component has no `cell` slot, so the the code doesn't make sense.  Whatever component does have a `cell` slot needs to be inserted first.